# Can I use the column name as condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which contains around a hundred columns.
Most of these columns are dates and I want to iterate through all these.

Here is an example :

| date | nbDays | 2020-12-20 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-30 | 4 |  |

IF date + nbdays <= 2020-12-20, set the value of this column to TRUE, FALSE if No.
The only thing I can't do is taking the column name as an argument in my condition, and do it for all these date columns.

Here's my expected output :

| date | nbDays | 2020-12-20 | 2020-12-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-30 | 4 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2020-12-18 | 2 | TRUE | FALSE |

Maybe in a loop but it'll be long to run?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: It depends on the actual type of the elements of the date column (are they strings or pd.Timestamps, or ...) and of the names of the other columns. Long story short, what are `type(df['date'].iloc[0])` and `type(df.columns[2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ensure your date columns are converted to datetime for this to work*

The basic steps I've used are:

1. get pandas to identify the date columns
2. shift the "date" column by nbDays
3. compare the shifted date column to the dates in the columns

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

shifted_date = [
    t + relativedelta(days=nb_days) 
      for t, nb_days in zip(df[date], df[nbDays])
]
date_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64]).columns

for date_column in date_columns:
    date_to_check = pd.to_datetime(date_column)
    
    df[date_column] = np.where(
         shifted_date <= date_to_check, True, False
    )
```

Don't be afraid to use a `for` loop here because the tough work is vectorised in the `np.where` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your `date_to_check` variable is one date, but I have to iterate the operation to all columns that contain a date in their name.
For example, for the column `2020-12-20`, I have to check if `shifted_date` <= `2020-12-20`. And same thing for all other columns (going from `2020-12-20` to XXXX)
 Maybe my question wasn't that clear sorry for that :/

Comment: Yes, sorry, was probably reading your question too quickly! I've updated my answer - that should work for you now

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of your columns are fixed, you can store the dates in a list or series, and then use it to generate values, like

```py
dates = df.columns[2:]
# be sure to convert them to some formats other than str
df.iloc[:,2:] = df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x:dates<=x.data+x.nbDays)
```

Comment: It's really bad practice to hard-code things based on a position. Also, you can't add a number to a datetime column, so this won't work anyway

Comment: You have a point, but sometimes a simple and flexible hard-code solution is enough.

Comment: If you are working to a tight deadline - maybe. But even in this example, it takes about two minutes to google how to infer the datetime columns, and then you know how to do it again in the future. So in my experience it's worth the extra time